# ReferenceError: provided is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I am completely new to react and I am stuck at this for many hours. The react part works well. I am adding `react-beautiful-dnd` to react. I am using npm to install the `react-beautiful-dnd` package. No other actions have been done on the package. I am following [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-reorder-a-list-with-react-beautiful-dnd) tutorial

```
const Component = wp.element.Component;
import initialData from './initial-data';
import Column from './column.jsx';
import {DragDropContext} from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

class App extends Component{
    state = initialData;
    render(){
        return(
            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
                {this.state.columnOrder.map(columnId => {
                    const column = this.state.columns[columnId];
                    const tasks = column.taskIds.map(taskId => this.state.tasks[taskId]);
                    return <Column key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasks} />;
                })}
            </DragDropContext>
        );
    }
}
wp.element.render(<App  />, document.getElementById('react_content'));
```

Column Component

```
const Component = wp.element.Component;
import Task from './task.jsx';
import {Droppable} from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

export default class Column extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div id="container">
            <h3>{this.props.column.title}</h3>
            <Droppable droppableId={this.props.column.id}>
                {provided => (
                    <div id="taskList" innerRef={provided.innerRef}{...provided.droppableProps}>
                      {this.props.tasks.map((task,index) => <Task key={task.id} task={task} index={index}  />)}
                      {provided.placeholder}
                    </div>
                )}
            </Droppable>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Task Component

```
const Component = wp.element.Component;
import { Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

export default class Task extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <Draggable draggableId={this.props.task.id} index={this.props.index}>
            (provided => {
                <div class="tasks"
                {...provided.draggableProps}
                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                innerRef={provided.innerRef}>
                {this.props.task.content}
                </div>
            })
        </Draggable>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting an error that `provided` is not defined. Is it because the package is not imported properly ? There is no error when creating a build of the react js.

Comment: Where is the provided  defined?

Comment: I do not see anything defined in the Column  class called provided

Comment: @zahrazamani I don't think that's the problem. Droppable is using the “render prop” pattern, i.e. it provides a function to its child components, which passes “provided” as an argument. So it should be defined

Comment: @PatrickHund Do you know what might be the issue ?

Comment: @zahrazamani As per the official tutorial, we don't have to define provided.

Comment: @melvin are you sure the error is in the Column component and not in the Task component?

Comment: Yes. @PatrickHund is correct. This is render props pattern used by that package. You don't have to define it anywhere. Do you have `<DragDropContext>` component ? https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/fb503621d6f314d744d868322abeaf9089236584/docs/api/drag-drop-context.md

Comment: @PatrickHund I have added the Task component code to the question. Please have a look

Comment: I think the “onDragEnd” method is missing in the App component, or did you just leave that out for brevity's sake?

Comment: @PatrickHund It is actually missing. Would that be a reason ?

Comment: @Dilshan I am using that in the first part of code. I mean in the `App` class

Comment: Possibly, if Droppable uses that for the provided argument, then it will be undefined

Comment: I have added the function `onDragEnd = result => {
    // TODO: reorder our column
   };` but the same issue persists.

Comment: maybe this link will help you https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1317

Comment: which version of react-beautiful-dnd are you using? the code example from the tutorial you are following uses version 8, which is quite old. the latest version is 13, there is a good chance that the API of the library has changed

Comment: try using version 8 explicitly, see if you code works then

Comment: Ok. I am using version 13. So is there any way instead of going back to version 8, I can fix the issue using 13 ?

Comment: I have tested this in version 8. The issue still exists

Comment: `const Component = wp.element.Component;` what's this ?

Comment: @Dilshan That's the WordPress way of using React Component.

Comment: @PatrickHund I have installed `react-beautiful-dnd` via npm and the package is available in node modules. I haven't done anything else to add the dnd package to the react. Is that ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for all your time and effort. The issue was with how I implemented `provided` wrapper in my code. I have changed the code to the following and now it works fine.

```
{(provided) => (

)}
```

Comment: So the parentheses around `provided` made the difference?

Comment: There is no other noticeable change in the code. I hope this is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
export default class Task extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
            super(props);
       }
      render() {
        return(
            <Draggable draggableId={this.props.task.id} index={this.props.index}>
    
             {(provided) => (
                  <div class="tasks"
                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                    ref={provided.innerRef}>
                    {this.props.task.content}
                    </div>
            )}
    </Draggable>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: The issue still exists

Comment: According to the new answer you gave, your problem was solved, right?

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. At first I thought it was due to the missing constructor. But later I saw atlassian github issue and saw the difference in brackets